# Repair range element switches?

Tags: switch, range

The switches on a couple of range elements don't work well anymore. Sometimes the burner will suddenly go on full heat while the switch is set to low or intermediate heat.

Is it possible to safely repair the switches, eg. with some alcohol or contact cleaner, or must they be replaced?

Switch model numbers: 3148954, 3148952

Range: Whirlpool YRF263LXTQ0

Comment: You mean the dial controls, right?

Comment: @isherwood Yes. Variously (and perhaps erroneously) called infinite switch, burner switch/control, thermostat, pot/potentiometer, heat/temperature control, etc

Comment: I suppose you could try but in my experience when they go bad they are usually toasted (literally).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my humble opinion, it isn't a good or safe idea to try and fix them. The bi-metal that controls the heat range of the burner is more than likely fatigued and can't be replaced. The switches are bracketed together in such a way that they are not meant to be taken apart and if you do, it's hard to get them securely put back together. Even if you could repair it, it would only be a temporary fix and could go out at any time or really over cook your food. Just get some new switches and do the job right.